# multithreading-Shared file access in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have method named WriteMsg it is called by several threads at same time, but i am getting an exception  **java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException**. how i can solve this? my code is similar like given below.

```
public void WriteMsg(string Msg)
{
    Mutex objMutex = new Mutex(false, "ThreadLock");
    objMutex.WaitOne(); 
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPathName, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Msg);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
    objMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    objMutex.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're getting a java exception in C#?

Comment: ;) Yes, but he mostly uses a method internal mutex - totally useless.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention I am calling some web services from inside this method. that is implemented using java.

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable for you to mark this method to allow one thread at a time?
Then each next call will be made, once the previous one has finished.

Put this attribute on your class:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
```

And the using statement:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh dude, you do not even kno what language you use?

The code is marked C#. THe error message is... java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException. Guess what - Java is not C#. Yopur code is C#, but the exception is Java - how come? I would strongly assume we do not see the whole story here. C# code does NOT throw Java exceptions.

Anyhow, the point being - simply do not access the same file from multiple threads at the same time y means of some sort of locking mechanism. Your approach with Mutex sounds sensible (but where does java come into the game given that you CLELARY use C# in the code?) I would start using ProcessExplorer and find out - ah - what is locking the file. It could be it is not wthe writer? Can it be it is something else that READS is? If it is out of process or something, then your Mutex will not help. A try / catch with a wait + retry may.

THAT SAID:

Check your mutex. YOu create the mutex in the method. THe WaitOne will never wait. YOu need to keep the Mutex between method calls and make sure all calls use the same Mutex. Right now you say like "Only the lowest number gets in" but you give eveyone a ticket with the same number. Mutex must be shared between all callers, sot it can not be defined within the method. Depending on class design you need an instance variable, static variable, dictionary opf mutexes (keyed by path).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention I am calling some web services from inside this method. that is implemented using java

Answer (score 0):

1) Assuming you just want all `WriteMsg` calls to run one after the other, you don't need to mess with Mutexes and you can just use C#'s [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement, which wraps a call to `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`.

2) Since you're using `using` on your StreamWriter, you don't need to manually Flush and Close.

So you method can look like this:

```
private object _lockObject = new object(); // shared by all threads.
public void WriteMsg(string Msg)
{
     lock (_lockObject)
     {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPathName, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(Msg);
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of creating a new `Mutex` in each call to this function ? Each thread is alone on its own `Mutex`... Make your `Mutex` shared by all threads.